# How to give alert based on the jquery ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In a php page , i have a ajax jquery code which calls my php controller to perform the particular action, When action returns success i am refreshing particular div.

My doubt is i i want to perform other actions when resonse come from my controller to my jquery function eg. if user is not logged in then i want to give a alert like `alert("Please login to continue");`

I have tried the below code but its not working at all. Please help

```
  <script type="text/javascript">         
        $('.voteup').click(function(e)
        {  
            // prevent the default action when a nav button link is clicked
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var $this = $(this),
            id = $this.data('id') 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            // ajax query to retrieve the HTML view without refreshing the page.
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:"<?php echo base_url('question/ajax_vote_up/'); ?>",
                data: {id: id},  
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (html) 
                { 
                    if(html == 'not_logged_in')//This is not working, not giving alert 
                    { 
                        alert("You need to login to vote.");
                    }
                     if(html == 'own_question')//This is not working, not giving alert 
                    { 
                        alert("You can not vote for your own question");
                    }
                    else{ //when success refresh the div
                        $('#questvotediv').html(html);}
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

In my Controller

```
function ajax_vote_up() 
{  

  $answer_id = $this->input->post('id'); 

   if ($answer_id > 0 && $this->session->userdata('logged_in') && $this->askmodel->get_user_id_By_answer_id($answer_id)!=$this->session->userdata('userid')) 
   {  
     //Few business logic related to my requirement
       $this->load->view('users/pages/show_question_By_id/votediv', $data); 
  }
   else if($this->askmodel->get_user_id_By_answer_id($answer_id)==$this->session->userdata('userid'))
  {
       //when user try to vote for their own quetion
     echo "own_question";
  }
  else
    {//Not looged in
      echo "not_logged_in";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is some response is coming or not from `php`?

Comment: have you tryed console.log(html) to see what response you are getting? are you sure your controller is not sending some layout information toguether with your echos?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yes it is comming.. if i give `alert(html)` then it is showing the result based on the controller code with big space in between result and intial state that's why it is not executing `if(html == 'own_question')`   because output is comming ` <space><space>     own_question`

Comment: what are you getting if you `alert(html)` in success function

Comment: @dreamCoder  I am getting the `<long space> not_logged_in` ,if i keep `alert(html);`  .I think this why i am unable to compare. Is there anything so that i can Trim those long spaces?

Comment: @cernunnos My controller is sending output.  I am getting the <long space> not_logged_in ,if i keep alert(html); .I think this why i am unable to compare. Is there anything so that i can Trim those long spaces?

Comment: @Ashutosh not possible because I cannt see any space in your controller .. have you tried to see reponse using firebug

Comment: @Ashutosh you can use jQuery.trim() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: FYI, no need to use `e.preventDefault();` twice along with `return false` at the end.

Comment: @cernunnos Yes thank you, working fine.After triming it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yu can try after trimming spaces

```
  success: function (html) 
           { 
                html = $.trim(html);
                if(html == 'not_logged_in')//This is not working, not giving alert 
                { 
                    alert("You need to login to vote.");
                }
                if(html == 'own_question')//This is not working, not giving alert 
                { 
                    alert("You can not vote for your own question");
                }
                else{ //when success refresh the div
                        $('#questvotediv').html(html);}
                }
```

Comment: I have to  refresh my particular div. Please read my quetion again. I need solution from my above jquery related

Comment: Try to alert html data in success  success: function (html) 
                { html = $.trim(html); alert(html); } then try

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to store response inside body first. Then You can check it.

<script type="text/javascript">         
    $('.voteup').click(function(e)
    {  
        // prevent the default action when a nav button link is clicked
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var $this = $(this),
        id = $this.data('id') 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // ajax query to retrieve the HTML view without refreshing the page.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:"<?php echo base_url('question/ajax_vote_up/'); ?>",
            data: {id: id},  
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (html) 
            { 
                $('#responseStore').html(html);

                if($('#responseStore').text() == 'not_logged_in')
                { 
                    alert("You need to login to vote.");
                }
                 if($('#responseStore').text() == 'own_question')
                { 
                    alert("You can not vote for your own question");
                }
                else{ //when success refresh the div
                    $('#questvotediv').html(html);}
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
<div style="display:none;" id="responseStore"></div>
```

Comment: Does this work, is it standard? If this solves the whitespace problem, I would love to see documentation as to why. Very curious, as this is an interesting solution.

Comment: Sure it will work because you are matching string so that there is no white space problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have some white spaces in the PHP document that are outputted before or after the echo command. if that is the case your comparrison could be messy.
Becuase of this, i usually prefer to work with INT as in your case you can set the return value of the PHP as 0 for not logged in and 1 for own question in then in your JS comparrison just use the parseFloat() function and comparte int's